# Remove Duplicate Item name in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Please help me. I want to show the username only once from firebase. Although the user have multiple record in the firebase, I just want to view the name of user who make order. The user can make multiple order, but I just want to show their name once.

I tried many ways but can't succeed. Someone who know about this? Thank you very much.

[image: This is my firebase]

[image: This is the result I get]

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        UID = this.getArguments().getString("UID");


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        wordDulicate = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(UID != null){
            mItemsKey = new ArrayList<>();
            mOrderedItemRef = mDatabase.child("OrderedItem");
            Log.d(TAG, " mOrderedItemRef:" + mOrderedItemRef);
            mOrderedItemVEL =  mOrderedItemRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mItems.clear();
                    mItemsKey.clear();
                    wordDulicate.clear();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        OrderedItem orderedItem = d.getValue(OrderedItem.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "orderedItem:" + orderedItem.getUserName());
                        mItems.add(orderedItem);
                        mItemsKey.add(d.getKey());
                    }
                    updateUI();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
                    Log.d(TAG, "get item databaseError: "+databaseError);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "UID: "+UID);

        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        //   if (mItemRef != null) mItemRef.removeEventListener(mItemVEL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        //  if (mItemRef != null) mItemRef.removeEventListener(mItemVEL);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_list_user_order, container, false);
        mItemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.admin_order_recycler_view);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mItemRecyclerView.getContext(), new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()).getOrientation());
        mItemRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        mItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Enter updateUI(); mItems: " + mItems);
        mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItems);
        mItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        OrderedItem mItems;
        TextView mNameTextView;

        ItemHolder(final View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_username);


          /*  if (UID != null) {
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "UID != null");
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                        builder
                                .setMessage("Delete This Item?")
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        deleteItem(mItems);
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }*/
        }

        void bindData(OrderedItem s){
           mItems = s;
           mNameTextView.setText(s.getUserName());



        }
    }

    private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder>{
        private ArrayList<OrderedItem> mItems;

        ItemAdapter(ArrayList<OrderedItem> Items){
            mItems = Items;
        }

        @Override
        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.admin_listed_user_order,parent,false);
            return new ItemHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
            OrderedItem s = mItems.get(position);
            holder.bindData(s);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to see our guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't post code or text as images (screenreaders!) Please format images correctly `![alt text](image url)`. Please take some time to create a [mcve], it makes it easier for everyone to understand your problem and verify their answer is correct. Note that the less time it takes other people to deal with your problem, the more likely you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you rely on a key and a value, why not use a map instead? Maps have a key and a value, and you can check whether or not an item with a key is present by getting the key, instead of having to iterate through the list and find duplicates.

First you need to initialize it:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<OrderedItem>> items = new HashMap<>();
```

The value is an ArrayList to keep any existing data

then put the items:

```
for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    OrderedItem orderedItem = d.getValue(OrderedItem.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "orderedItem:" + orderedItem.getUserName());
    items.putIfAbsent(d.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());//create a list if it doesn't exist
    items.get(d.geyKey()).add(orderedItem);//add the item

}
```

and clearing with a map is the same as with lists